# Why is my else clause not working in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a search error for my ecommerce website. When a user inputs a search that is not in the database, it should return the search error page. Though it seems my else clause isn't working.

I tried putting the else clause in the search.html page, but it keeps giving me errors and it seems when I try to fix the errors, nothing really happens, it stays the same. I expect the search_error.html page to appear when the user inputs a product name that is not in the database. Though I keep getting for example, when I type "hello," the page appears with "Search results for hello." But it should result the search_error.html page. I also tried currently a else clause in my views.py, but it shows the same thing. I think my else clause isn't working and I don't know why.

My views.py:

```
def search(request):
    if 'searched' in request.GET:
        searched = request.GET['searched']
        products = Product.objects.filter(title__icontains=searched)
        return render(request, 'epharmacyweb/search.html', {'searched': searched, 'products': products})
    else:
        return render(request, 'epharmacyweb/search_error.html')

def search_error(request):
    return render(request, 'epharmacyweb/search_error.html')
```

My urls.py under URLPatterns:

```
path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
path('search_error/', views.search_error, name='search_error'),
```

My search.html page:

```
{% if searched %}
            <div class="pb-3 h3">Search Results for {{ searched }}</div>
              <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-5 g-3">
                {% for product in products %}
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm">
                          <img class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" src="{{ product.image.url }}">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">
                              <a class="text-dark text-decoration-none" href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
                            </p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                              <small class="text-muted"></small>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
              </div>
                <br></br>

        {% else %}
            <h1>You haven't searched anything yet...</h1>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: The problem isn't the `else`. `'searched' in request.GET` isn't doing any checks of the database. It's only checking if the user entered a search query. You would need to check the length of `products` to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: `if 'searched' in request.GET` This just means that the user **wants** to do a search.  You need to **perform** the search, and then see if there are any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` is returning true because the term `'searched'` *is* in fact in the `request.GET` dictionary.  That doesn't mean that there is a product in your database with the value `request.GET['searched']`, which might be "hello" when you type in "hello".  `request.GET` is a dictionary with a *key* of `'searched'` and a value of "hello".  You can also use `get()`, which will either get the value of `request['searched']` or return `None`, so you do not have to check it with an if at all.

Now to check if the database has the value of the search term, you can check the queryset:

```py
def search(request):
    
    # Return the value or None
    searched = request.GET.get('searched')

    products = Product.objects.filter(title__icontains=searched)

    # Check if there are any products with the search term:
    if products:
        return render(request, 'epharmacyweb/search.html', {'searched': searched, 'products': products})
    else:
        return render(request, 'epharmacyweb/search_error.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check if `products = Product.objects.filter(title__icontains=searched)` is returning results instead of checking if "searched" is in the `GET` arguments.

To check if the database returned results you can you `exists()`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists